# Mongodb-go-driver interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.ObjectID, not primitive.ObjectID (types from different packages)

Tags: mongodb, go

I can display the result.InsertedID with no problem, however, I keep getting the above error when I attempt to access the value to use it other places. I want to get the value before I leave the method that inserts the new object.  The error message does not make any sense.

I get this error with res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID). What is the proper way?

How do I get the concrete value preferably as a hex string?  Even if I can get the value as a concrete ObjectID and not an interface I would be happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two packages in the application with name `primitive` containing a type named `ObjectID`.  The concrete value in the [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) is from one of those packages.  The asserted type is from the other package. The type assertion panics because the types are not equal.

Fix by modifying the application to use a single import path for the `primitive` package (and the entire driver).

The canonical import path of the package was changed from `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/primitive` to `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive` in February 2019. It is likely that the application uses both of these import paths.

Comment: this should be accepted answer, this indeed in the reason for the above error